# How do I search-and-replace strings (not regex) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, replace

I have used gsub previously for a regex match, but what should I call for string literals?

I want to replace `pair[0]` with `pair[1]` wherever `pair[0]` is found in the file.

```
text = File.read( fname )  
@hash_old_to_new.each do
  |pair|
  puts "\tReplacing " + pair[0] + " with " + pair[1]
  # result = text.gsub( /pair[0]/, pair[1] )  <--- this is no good
end
File.open( fname, "w" ) { |file| file << result }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gsub` also works for string literals.

```
text.gsub!(pair[0], pair[1])
```

Note that `gsub` returns a new String, rather than modifying the existing String "in place". Because of the way your code is written, this will cause you to lose updates. You can use `gsub!`, or else you can chain calls like this:

```
text = text.gsub(pair[0], pair[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You were not far from the answer:

Directly use string in gsub:

```
result = text.gsub( pair[0], pair[1] )
```

Or use a string in regex:

```
result = text.gsub( /#{pair[0]}/, pair[1] )
```

Comment: No reason to use a literal regex. Not sure how this improves on the existing answer.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am just giving all possible solutions in case someone googled and come in here.